# Error on refreshing auth token in Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to refresh my auth token in Firebase using swift as follows

```
let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true) { idToken, error in
    if error != nil {
       return;
    }
    self.userDataManager.fetchUser()
}
```

It's hitting the error return statement with,

```
message = "Requests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked.";
status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
```

I search around the docs, But couldn't find a proper solution for this. Please help with this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error but with the Web APIs. Solved it by

1. Going to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials,
2. Clicking on the API key
3. Enabling the "Token Service API", along with "Identity Toolkit API"